# delphi cxDateNavigator prevent date less than today

Tags: delphi

I am trying to prevent selection of a date that is less than today in the cxDateNavigator.
However when I select the date today I trigger the message. What am I missing here ?

```
procedure TForm9.cxDateNavigator1SelectionChanged(Sender: TObject; const AStart,
  AFinish: TDateTime);
begin
if cxDateNavigator1.Date <Now  then
showmessage('yo.');
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the cxDateNavigator control, but I think the problem is that "Now" returns both date and time. A TDateTime variable internally is a number with decimals, the "date" part is stored as integer and the "time" as the decimals. So you should cut off the Time/decimals, so you compare just the Date part without the time.
Like this:

```
procedure TForm9.cxDateNavigator1SelectionChanged(Sender: TObject; const AStart, AFinish: TDateTime);
begin
    if Trunc(cxDateNavigator1.Date) < Trunc(Now) then
        showmessage('yo.');     
end;
```

Comment: Or, instead of `Trunc(Now)` use `Today` (in `System.DateUtils`) which returns the date of today, without the time part.

Comment: In my opinion `Trunc()` is a bad idea, use `System.DateUtils.DateOf()` instead. There are scenarios were `Trunc()` returns a wrong value, for example in SQL as a parameter.